# How to activate a remote Python conda environment with Tramp / SSH?

Tags: python, tramp, doom, anaconda-mode

I'm using Doom Emacs 27.2 on linux. I have (python +lsp +pyright +conda +cython) in my init file and `(setq conda-anaconda-home "~/miniconda")` in `config.el`.

I can activate local conda env by `M-x conda-env-activate` but I can't choose a remote conda env since it's not listed there.

How I can activate a remote Python conda environment with Tramp over SSH?

Answer (score 1):

conda seems to not work with remote environments [link](https://github.com/necaris/conda.el/issues/30). You mind have some luck with conda and lsp, or even the default python-mode using `python-shell-virtualenv-root` to a remote tramp address, in which case let us know.

`anaconda-mode` [link](https://github.com/pythonic-emacs/anaconda-mode) and its `pythonic-activate` work with remote virtual environments. This is an alternative to the lsp+conda combo. You can also run the `run-python` in the remote environment.

If the environment is in conda and you also have jupyter, you can also run remote kernels with `emacs-jupyter` [link](https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter). Although with this you do not edit remote py files using a remote environment, you can edit them locally and with local lsp+conda but send python commands to the remote kernel.

Comment: +1 for pythonic-activate